# How to sample continuous signal correctly?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, sampling

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

j = 1j
pi = np.pi


interval = 0.5
fs = 1024
Ts = 1/fs
N = np.uint(interval*fs)
t = np.linspace(0, interval - Ts, N)
freq = 2*pi/N * np.arange(N)
f0 = 16 

# x(t) = sin(2pi * f0 * t)
# a[n] = x(n*Ts) = sin(2pi * f0 * n * Ts)
n = np.arange(N)
a = np.sin(2*pi*f0*Ts*n) 



# visualisation de a
# on ajoute a droite la valeur de gauche pour la periodicite
plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot( t, a)

# calcul de A
A = 1/N * np.fft.fft(a)

# visualisation de A
# on ajoute a droite la valeur de gauche pour la periodicite

plt.subplot(312)
plt.plot(freq, np.real(A))

plt.ylabel("Real Part")

plt.subplot(313)
plt.plot(freq, np.imag(A))


plt.ylabel("Imaginary Part")

plt.show()
```

So I have a signal $$x(t) = \sin(2\pi \cdot  f_0 \cdot  t),\ t = 0\rightarrow0.5s$$

I wish to sample the signal at $f_s = 1024\ \mathrm{H_z} \longrightarrow T_s = 1/1024$

So I make $$a[n] = x(n\cdot T_s) \longrightarrow a[n] = \sin(2\pi\cdot f_0\cdot T_s\cdot n)$$

But clearly, this makes the discrete signal have $f = f_0\cdot T_s$.

So when I FFT $a[n]$, the 2 frequency spike is at the wrong location. You can see that the $\sin$ spike is at $2\pi\cdot f_0\cdot T_s$, instead of $2\pi\cdot f_0$

[image]

I don't want to make $$a[n] = \sin(2\pi\cdot f_0\cdot n)$$ because then I only get the values of $x(t)$ at positions $t = 2\pi\cdot f_0\cdot n$

Which step did I forget (or did wrong)? How to sample the $x(t)$ so that the FFT is correct? Thank you.

Comment: The relative frequency in discrete time can be defined as $f=F/F_s$ which you got it right with your equation $f=f_0 * T_s$. If you perform FFT on $a[n]$ you may see the spectral content concentrated at $f$.

Comment: The FFT of $\sin$ whose spectrum might resemble like a spike must be at $f=f_0*T_s$, if you plotted using relative frequency instead of $n$

Comment: so what should I add so that the graph has 2 spike at 2*pi*16 ? (the original frequency in continuous time)

Comment: You may use fftshift (python equivalent I have no idea)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
close all;
clear all;

interval        = 0.5;
f0              = 16; 
t               = 0:1/2048:interval-(1/2048)
x_t             = sin(2*pi*f0*t);

figure(1);
subplot(2, 1, 1);
plot(t, x_t);
axis([0 interval])
hold on;

fs              = 1024;
N               = (interval * fs);
sample_index    = [0:N-1];
x_n             = sin(2*pi*(f0/fs)*sample_index);

n               = 0:1/fs:interval-(1/fs)

stem(n, x_n);


X               = fftshift(fft(x_n, N));

df              = fs / N;
sampleIndex     = -N/2:N/2-1;
relative_f      = sampleIndex * df;

subplot(2, 1, 2);
stem(relative_f, abs(X));
xlabel('f (Hz)'); ylabel('|X(k)|');
axis([min(relative_f) max(relative_f)])
```

[image]